# lua_close() crash when there is too many lua_state in an vector of objects in C

Tags: c++, lua, segmentation-fault

so there is a main_window class that handling everything  the thing that's important here is the Vector of enemy, enemies, at the time enemy is dead, it will push back a effect object into the vector of Effect. and here come the the handy point

```
lua_State *G = luaL_newstate(); // I need this thing to be global

// class constructor
Effect::Effect(int ix, int iy)
{
  // not important codes deleted
  luaL_openlibs(G);
  luaL_dofile(G, "script/effect/blue_explosion.lua");
  lua_getglobal(G, "draw_x");
  draw_x = lua_tointeger(G, -1);
  lua_getglobal(G, "draw_y");
  draw_y = lua_tointeger(G, -1);
  /* the function name */
  lua_getfield(G, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "setup");
  /* the first argument */
  lua_pushnumber(G, ix);
  /* the second argument */
  lua_pushnumber(G, iy);
  /* call the function with 2 arguments, return 1 result */
  lua_call(G, 2, 0);
}
```

these things are going fine by itself, but here comes the problem

```
void Effect::close_lua()
{
    lua_close(G);
}
```

which is called upon the end of life of the effect
with out this closure, it will start eat up my Ram
but if I use this, and lot's Effect object was created, the thing will crash with a
Access violation (segmentation fault)

anyone that have an idea how to fix this?

or should I just change an scripting language?

it seems like i had close one state twice, but the lua_close(G) is in different objects that's in the same vector, i just think up a way, maybe i can put lua_states in a vector too?

Comment: "*anyone have an idea how to fix this?*" yeah, make sure you're not closing a given state twice. eg. `assert(G); lua_close(G); G = NULL;`

Comment: @greatwolf you are actually kind of right! because i didn't make lua_state *G private, it's reused in other objects

Comment: Keep your original question as it was and post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved! what i did was make the lua_state object to **private** and it's not crashing anymore, it's probably is because that lua_state pointer got copied to other places, so now after i made it private it's not **copyable** anymore!

so first in **header**, **private section** declare lua_State *G;
and use G = luaL_newstate(); in the constructer

and some how it won't work in destructor, so i had this in the loop

```
for(int i = effects->size()-1; i > -1 ; i--)
{
    effects->at(i).act();
    if(effects->at(i).should_remove())
    {
        effects->at(i).close_lua();
        effects->erase(effects->begin()+i);
    }
}
```

that manually run the close_lua() witch is

```
void Effect::close_lua()
{
    lua_close(G);
    //std::cout << "closed"; a chick line
}
```

these lines worked perfectly as i watching the memory of the program in task manager